# Upload Video to Facebook from AIR app

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, air, adobe

Developing an AIR based app that captures video. The user will then be able to upload to facebook if they so choose.

Right now I am confused about the requirements in uploading videos to facebook.

Even though this is technically NOT a facebook application, will I need to create a Facebook application ID?

Will I also need to make use of the facebook-actionscript SDK?

I've read elsewhere that the API needs to launch the Facebook login within a web view.

Or are there alternatives in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Even though this is technically NOT a facebook application, will I need to create a Facebook application ID?

Yes.

> Will I also need to make use of the facebook-actionscript SDK? Or are there alternatives in my case?

Talking to the API works over HTTP – so you can use any technique that allows you to make HTTP requests.

But using a framework/SDK that already has methods for usual FB API stuff will be much simpler, than handling all that HTTP stuff yourself.

Comment: Thanks. So I assume it is NOT possible to enable the sign in process ENTIRELY within a desktop app? The user must switch to a web interface to complete the process?